# IdentityServer3 Multi Tenant IdSvr (single instance) with Multi Tenant Api (single instance) - needed multiple authserver addresses

Tags: identityserver3

We have IdSvr single instance with Web Api single instance that both support multi tenant. Our web app is deployed to multiple domains with their own styling on each. The business does not want them to be redirected to the IdSvr such as http://multiauth.identityserver.com. They want to go from a website domain to the IdSvr using http://auth.websitedomain1.com and another would use http://auth.websitedomain2.com, etc

The issue is with the Web Api and setting up the Bearer authentication.

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = Constants.BaseAddress,
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "cspwebapi" },

            // client credentials for the introspection endpoint
            ClientId = "cspclient",
            ClientSecret = "8BE96BA5-79F1-4FA4-8E41-6BCE7EA7090F",
        });
```

I can only specify http://multiauth.identityserver.com as the Authority and not multiple such as http://auth.websitedomain1.com and http://auth.websitedomain2.com. The client gets a 401.

So far I have the single instance IdSvr with bindings auth.websitedomain1.com, auth.websitedomain2.com, auth.websitedomain3.com.  Now on the Web Api (resource server) I iterate through the array of domain names and create a new app.Map(....) with each domain for the Authority property.  The resource server spins up without issue meaning it can see the IdSvr at each domain name.  The app.Map(....) segment needs to be the same for all of them...I now have found that doing app.Map('') for all of them will not work for the second or third domain name.  Am I on to something here or is this the wrong approach?  How else can I configure this to work per the requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple instances of `UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` in your pipeline, one for each of your IdentityServer installations, each configured with a different authentication scheme (`AuthenticationType`).

Then in your authorization logic, you can check what auth scheme the token authenticated with and authorize access to data accordingly.

Comment: Essentially what you're saying is pass a string value from the cookie and inspect it to see if its on a list of allowed values in a custom AuthorizeAttribute within the WebApi?  So do I set a user claim for this on the IdSvr side?  How does IdSvr send the AuthenticationType property to the client?  I'm using ItentityServer3 and not 4, 4 does have a scheme property...3 does not.

Comment: No, not from a cookie. The token will be validated by one of your token middlewares, which will as a result issue a claims identity that will include the AuthenticationType that issued the identity. The AuthenticationType property is on the IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions middleware. This value can then be used during authorization.

Comment: I don't follow. How will the token be validated? Do you have any puedo code for this? And this validation is in the webapi client, correct?  Also, on the IdSvr what exactly do I need to do, puedo code? I'm so lost by your response even more then before. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Your API validates incoming access tokens using the `UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` middleware. This middleware validates tokens from a specific (single) authority, so if you have multiple token issuers (authorities), then you need multiple instances of this middleware.

Comment: Thanks again @Scott Bradley. However, I have a single issuer, single instance IdSvr. I want it to support multiple domain names. I suppose having multiple IdSvr instances running in the pipeline for each domain name and having the same running for each on the Web api client would work. Right?